# how to loop through each row in excel spreadsheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to make the first column of each row in an excel spreadsheet as a key and rest of the values in that row as its value so that I can store them in a dictionary.
The problem is, when I loop through the rows and columns all the row values are getting stored in every key.

```
import openpyxl

from openpyxl import load_workbook

file = "test.xlsx"

#load the work book
wb_obj = load_workbook(filename = file)

wsheet = wb_obj['test']

#dictionary to store data
dataDict = {}

value = []

row_count = wsheet.max_row
col_count = wsheet.max_column

# loop to get row and column values
for i in range(2, row_count+1):
    for j in range(i, col_count+1):
        key   = wsheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
        print (key)
        value.append(wsheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value)
        print (value)

    dataDict[key] = value

#prompt user for input
userInput = input("Please enter an id to find a person's details: ")

print (dataDict.get(int(userInput)))
```

data in spreadsheet: 
[image]

Result I'm expecting:
{1: ['John', 'Doe', 4567891234, 'johndoe@jd.ca'], 2: ['Wayne 'Kane', 1234567891, 'wd@wd.ca']}

Result I got:
{1: ['John', 'Doe', 4567891234, 'johndoe@jd.ca', 'Kane', 1234567891, 'wd@wd.ca'], 2: ['John', 'Doe', 4567891234, 'johndoe@jd.ca', 'Kane', 1234567891, 'wd@wd.ca']}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Openpyxl already has a proper way to iterate through rows using `worksheet.iter_rows()`. You can use it to unpack the first cell's value as the key and the values from the other cells as the list in the dictionary, repeating for every row.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file = "test.xlsx" #load the work book
wb_obj = load_workbook(filename = file)
wsheet = wb_obj['test']
dataDict = {}

for key, *values in wsheet.iter_rows():
    dataDict[key.value] = [v.value for v in values]
```

Comment: How to omit first row in excel from this loop if we have names for columns like id, first name, last name, phone, etc

Comment: Use the keyword argument `min_row` to specify from which row to start iterating: `wsheet.iter_rows(min_row=2)`.

Comment: This openpyxl library hasn't been updated since 2015